# How do I detect when the content of a WebBrowser control has changed (in design mode)?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm using a `WebBrowser` control in design mode.

```cs
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
doc.designMode = "On";
```

I have a save button that I would like to enable or disable depending on whether the contents of the control have changed.

I also need to know when the contents of the control have changed as I need to stop the user from navigating away from the control without accepting a confirmation message box stating that their changes will be lost.

I can't find any events that would let me know that the contents have changed.

Comment: Just don't.  Design mode is for programmers, they have source control to clean up big messes.  Spamming him with "are you sure" prompts is just annoying, he's sure 99.9% of the time.  Write javascript if you want to do this anyway.

Comment: What do you mean? This is a WinForms app that lets the user edit some HTML content within a web browser control. They select what they're editing from a treeview and I need to confirm with them that they are aware that they will lose their changes if they try to navigate away without saving. It's not a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such event since DocumentText is a simple string.
I would create a string variable storing the last saved text and check it at each KeyDown / MouseDown / Navigating event.

```
string lastSaved;

private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Load the form then save WebBrowser text
   this.lastSaved = this.webBrowser1.DocumentText;
}

private void webBrowser1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if it changed
    if (this.lastSaved != this.webBrowser1.DocumentText)
    {
        // TODO: changed, enable save button
        this.lastSaved = this.webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    }
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if it changed
    if (this.lastSaved != this.webBrowser1.DocumentText)
    {
        // TODO: ask user if he wants to save
        // You can set e.Cancel = true to cancel loading the next page
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a KeyDown event for the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser - the only key event it supports is PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: This doesn't take into account if there is `TAB` or arrow keys pressed. Also it doesn't register change when images are resized, moved etc. See my solution.

Answer (score 3):

`QueryInterface()` the document for `IMarkupContainer2`, then call `IMarkupContainer2::RegisterForDirtyRange` with your own implementation of `IHTMLChangeSink`. Your `IHTMLChangeSink::Notify` implementation will be called when a change is made.

Note: Do this after you set the design mode. The document gets reloaded and event hook get lost, if you toggle the design mode.

Comment: This sounds like a good implementation, but it's a little too abstract for my skill level.  Could you give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

another solution, if you implement `IDocHostUIHandler`, you can use its method `UpdateUI`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work - `QueryInterface()` for [IPersistFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersistfile) interface and use [IPersistFile::IsDirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ipersistfile-isdirty) method with the return value of `S_OK` (if dirty or if the design mode document has been modified).

You don't need to use `IPersistFile::Load` to load the contents into the web browser, `WebBrowser->Navigate()` will also work fine.

Note - there is a same `IsDirty()` method also in [IPersistStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersiststream) and [IPersistStreamInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ocidl/nn-ocidl-ipersiststreaminit) interfaces

I don't use C# but it should be relatively easy to rewrite.

```cpp
bool IsEditorDirty(WebBrowser* WB)
    {
    // beware, if it fails to get Document and IPersistFile it will not register as dirty
    bool isdirty = false;

    IHTMLDocument2* pDoc2 = WB->Document;

    if (pDoc2) {
        IPersistFile* pPFile;

        if (pDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&diPFile) == S_OK) {
            isdirty = (pPFile->IsDirty() == S_OK);
            pPFile->Release();
            }
    
        pDoc2->Release();
        }

    return isdirty;
    }
```