# Detecting changes in an editable TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I'm loading an HTML local file into `TWebBrowser` as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file:///C:\Tmp\input.html');
end;
```

In the `TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete` event handler I'm making it editable:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).designMode := 'on';
end;
```

I need to be notified as soon as the user applies any changes through the `TWebBrowser` (i.e: he writes something...) but I can't see any `OnChanged` or similar event handler.

---

I've tried capturing `WM_PASTE` and `WM_KEYDOWN` but my code is never executed:

```
  TMyWebBrowser = class(TWebBrowser)
  public
    procedure WM_Paste(var Message: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
    procedure WM_KeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
  end;

...

procedure TMyWebBrowser.WM_Paste(var Message: TWMPaste);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('Paste');
end;

procedure TMyWebBrowser.WM_KEYDOWN(var Message: TWMKeyDown);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('KeyDown');
end;
```

I've also tried setting the `WindowProc` property but without any success.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Olivier: Because I would like to enable/disable a save button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture changes to the document in design mode you should use its [`IMarkupContainer2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa703628(v%3Dvs.85)) interface to register an [`IHTMLChangeSink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa704257%28v%3Dvs.85%29) via [`RegisterForDirtyRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa703629(v=vs.85)) method. The process is pretty simple - implement `IHTMLChangeSink`, obtain `IMarkupContainer2` from `WebBrowser1.Document` and call its `RegisterForDirtyRange` method, but there's a catch.

When you change the `designMode` of `IHTMLDocument2`, `TWebBrowser` control reloads the current document and it loses all registered change sinks. Therefore you should register it after putting the document in design mode. After that you receive change notifications via `IHTMLChangeSink.Notify` method.

But there's another catch. Since entering the design mode causes reloading of the document and that in turn causes changing the `readyState` property of the document to `'loading'` and then consecutively to `'complete'`. Your change sink will receive those `readyState` change notifications. Note that `TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete` **is not** invoked after entering design mode. That's why you should ignore any notifications until the document is fully reloaded in design mode.

Another minor complication is that `RegisterForDirtyRange` creates a cookie that you need to maintain in order to unregister the change sink. Since you need a class to implement `IHTMLChangeSink` anyway, it could also encapsulate the design mode state and change registration.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, SHDocVw, MSHTML;

const
  DesignMode: array[Boolean] of string = ('off', 'on');

type
  TWebBrowserDesign = class(TInterfacedObject, IHTMLChangeSink)
  private
    FDirtyRangeCookie: LongWord;
    FDocumentComplete: Boolean;
    FHTMLDocument2: IHTMLDocument2;
    FMarkupContainer2: IMarkupContainer2;
    FOnChange: TProc;
    { IHTMLChangeSink }
    function Notify: HResult; stdcall;
  public
    constructor Create(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; const AOnChange: TProc);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TWebBrowserDesign.Create(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; const AOnChange: TProc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  if not Assigned(WebBrowser) then
    raise Exception.Create('Web browser control missing.');
  if not Supports(WebBrowser.Document, IHTMLDocument2, FHTMLDocument2) then
    raise Exception.Create('No HTML document loaded.');
  FHTMLDocument2.designMode := DesignMode[True];
  if Supports(WebBrowser.Document, IMarkupContainer2, FMarkupContainer2) then
  begin
    if FMarkupContainer2.RegisterForDirtyRange(Self, FDirtyRangeCookie) <> S_OK then
      FDirtyRangeCookie := 0
    else
      _Release;
  end;
  FOnChange := AOnChange;
end;

destructor TWebBrowserDesign.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FMarkupContainer2) and (FDirtyRangeCookie <> 0) then
    FMarkupContainer2.UnRegisterForDirtyRange(FDirtyRangeCookie);
  if Assigned(FHTMLDocument2) then
    FHTMLDocument2.designMode := DesignMode[False];
  inherited;
end;

function TWebBrowserDesign.Notify: HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
  if not FDocumentComplete then
    FDocumentComplete := FHTMLDocument2.readyState = 'complete'
  else if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange();
end;
```

Note the call to `_Release` after registering the change sink. This is to "prevent" markup container from holding strong reference to `TWebBrowserDesign` instance. That allows you to control design mode using the lifetime of `TWebBrowserDesign` instance:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    { ... }
  private
    FWebBrowserDesign: IInterface;
    { ... }
  end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  { enter design mode }
  FWebBrowserDesign := TWebBrowserDesign.Create(WebBrowser1, procedure
    begin
      ButtonSave.Enabled := True;
    end);
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonSave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { exit design mode }
  FWebBrowserDesign := nil;
  ButtonSave.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Alternatively you can implement change sink as a component.

```
type
  TWebBrowserDesign = class(TComponent, IHTMLChangeSink)
  private
    FDirtyRangeCookie: LongWord;
    FDocumentComplete: Boolean;
    FHTMLDocument2: IHTMLDocument2;
    FMarkupContainer2: IMarkupContainer2;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FWebBrowser: TWebBrowser;
    procedure EnterDesignMode;
    procedure ExitDesignMode;
    function GetActive: Boolean;
    procedure SetActive(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetWebBrowser(const Value: TWebBrowser);
    { IHTMLChangeSink }
    function Notify: HResult; stdcall;
  protected
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Active: Boolean read GetActive write SetActive;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property WebBrowser: TWebBrowser read FWebBrowser write SetWebBrowser;
  end;

destructor TWebBrowserDesign.Destroy;
begin
  ExitDesignMode;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWebBrowserDesign.EnterDesignMode;
begin
  if not Assigned(FWebBrowser) then
    raise Exception.Create('Web browser control missing.');
  if not Supports(FWebBrowser.Document, IHTMLDocument2, FHTMLDocument2) then
    raise Exception.Create('No HTML document loaded.');
  try
    FHTMLDocument2.designMode := DesignMode[True];
    if Supports(FWebBrowser.Document, IMarkupContainer2, FMarkupContainer2) then
    begin
      if FMarkupContainer2.RegisterForDirtyRange(Self, FDirtyRangeCookie) <> S_OK then
        FDirtyRangeCookie := 0;
    end;
  except
    ExitDesignMode;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TWebBrowserDesign.ExitDesignMode;
begin
  if Assigned(FMarkupContainer2) then
  begin
    if FDirtyRangeCookie <> 0 then
    begin
      FMarkupContainer2.UnRegisterForDirtyRange(FDirtyRangeCookie);
      FDirtyRangeCookie := 0;
    end;
    FMarkupContainer2 := nil;
  end;
  if Assigned(FHTMLDocument2) then
  begin
    FHTMLDocument2.designMode := DesignMode[False];
    if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then
      FHTMLDocument2 := nil; { causes AV when its hosting TWebBrowser component is destroying; I didn't dig into details }
  end;
  FDocumentComplete := False;
end;

function TWebBrowserDesign.GetActive: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Assigned(FHTMLDocument2);
end;

procedure TWebBrowserDesign.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FWebBrowser) then
    WebBrowser := nil;
end;

function TWebBrowserDesign.Notify: HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
  if not FDocumentComplete then
    FDocumentComplete := FHTMLDocument2.readyState = 'complete'
  else if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TWebBrowserDesign.SetActive(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Active <> Value then
  begin
    if Value then
      EnterDesignMode
    else
      ExitDesignMode;
  end;
end;

procedure TWebBrowserDesign.SetWebBrowser(const Value: TWebBrowser);
begin
  if Assigned(FWebBrowser) then
  begin
    ExitDesignMode;
    FWebBrowser.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
  end;
  FWebBrowser := Value;
  if Assigned(FWebBrowser) then
    FWebBrowser.FreeNotification(Self);
end;
```

If you put such a component in a design-time package and register it within the IDE, then you'll be able to link this component with `TWebBrowser` and assign `OnChange` event handler in the form designer. Use `Active` property in code to enter/exit the design mode.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    { ... }
    WebBrowserDesign1: TWebBrowserDesign;
    { ... }
  end;

procedure WebBrowserDesign1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonSave.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  { enter design mode }
  WebBrowserDesign1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonSave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { exit design mode }
  WebBrowserDesign1.Active := False;
  ButtonSave.Enabled := False;
end;
```

NB: Similar question has been asked regarding C#/WinForms - [How do I detect when the content of a WebBrowser control has changed (in design mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135743/how-do-i-detect-when-the-content-of-a-webbrowser-control-has-changed-in-design/11163073)

Final note: I'm not convinced that enabling save button after a change is the best UX design. If you think that the code above is worth to achieve your goal then go ahead. This is just a proof of concept and the code hasn't been thoroughly tested. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Great answer! Far beyond my expectations! I've tried both ways and it seems that both works good. I've found only two problems: 1) On _Delphi XE7_ I can't find `DesignMode[True]`/`DesignMode[False]` so I've switched them to `'on'`/`'off'`. 2) At the first change, the `OnChange` is not executed because it sets `FDocumentComplete` to `True` and doesn't execute the `OnChange`, I've slighlty modified the `Notify` method: `Result := S_OK; if not FDocumentComplete then FDocumentComplete := FHTMLDocument2.readyState = 'complete'; if FDocumentComplete and Assigned(FOnChange) then FOnChange(Self);`

Comment: @Fabrizio I've added missing code - see `const` in the first code block. As for the `FDocumentComplete` flag - I was getting 2 notifications after entering the design mode with no user modification. I the first notification `readyState` was `'loading'` and in the second it was `'complete'`. This may probably vary depending on IE version / IE document mode.

Comment: Thanks, I have IE 11.900.18362.0. What do you mean for "IE document mode" and how can I check which one is the `TWebBrowser` using?

Comment: [Fix web compatibility issues using document modes and the Enterprise Mode site list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/fix-compat-issues-with-doc-modes-and-enterprise-mode-site-list). A topic related to web browser control and document mode: [WebBrowser control set Document Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690072/webbrowser-control-set-document-mode).